# linux - copy/paste in a terminal session

Tags: linux, terminal, copy, clipboard, paste

How do I get the copy/paste functionality **in a terminal session** in Linux (i. e. **with no desktop at all**, like when you press `Alt+Ctrl+F1` in Ubuntu)? Is there a package that could substitute `Ctrl+Shift+C` and `Ctrl+Shift+V` functionality that exists in desktop terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at `xclip` in Linux:

```
echo hello | xclip
```

To copy to the clipboard. Then:

```
xclip -o
```

to paste it. Depending on what you want to do, there are also the `crtl+u` to cut a line from the terminal, and `crtl+y` to paste it (on the same terminal only though).

Hope it helps!

Comment: xclip didn't work, I get 'Error: can't open display: (null)'.  `ctrl+y` and `ctrl+u` are a nice one, though you seem to have mixed them up :)

Comment: if you're trying `xclip` on a remote server, a `ssh -X` would get rid of the error. Sorry for the mixup, I just edited my previous answer.